# Ubuntu 12.04 (Gnome classic) Custom Application Launcher in Linux Mint 17

Tags: cinnamon, drag-and-drop

On Ubuntu 12.04 (in Gnome classic mode) I have a Custom Application Launcher that launches a small script, `drop_on_me`, whenever I drag and drop a URL from the address bar in Firefox or Chrome onto it.¹ I drag the URL by clicking the (Identity) icon next to the URL.

[image]

How can achieve the same effect in Linux Mint 17 under Cinnamon, either with an application on the desktop or an applet in the panel?

There doesn't seem to be a simple way to add any existing script just like I have in Ubuntu. When you drag and drop something on a menu/taskbar applet the application doesn't start, so I am not even sure an applet would be the right thing to look for. E.g. when you drag a URL from chrome to the Firefox icon on the taskbar, Firefox doesn't start, let alone start and display the URL dragged on it.

I have looked at extending the context menu when clicking on the address bar, but that would require different implementations for Firefox and Chrome, and that in JavaScript as well.²

---

The script analyses the URL and takes action based on that. It does handle multiple domains with different actions. E.g. if a stackexchange/stackoverflow URL is dropped on it, a new directory `<SE_SITE>_<QUESTION_ID>_<QUESTION_TITLE>` is created under `~/src/stackexchange/`, which I use as sandbox to experiment with files for a possible answer. An accompanying alias `cdsx`:

```
alias cdsx='cd ~/src/stackexchange; cd $(ls -t | head -1)'
```

gets me to that directory in any open bash shell.

---

¹<sub>You can launch "Add to Panel" with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+right mouse click</sub>
²<sub>Going that route would have the advantage of also being able to handle URLs on a page, without first opening the page and getting the URL in the address bar.</sub>

Comment: This has been one of the things holding me back from switching to Mint from my current, working, work environment. And I think it is the last thing left to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For now I found a workaround in that I just drop the URL on the
desktop. A program runs in the background and watches for any `.desktop` files created there and

- parses its content to get the URL
- launches `drop_on_me` if URL found
- deletes the `.desktop` file

This has the advantage that I no longer have to aim for the
application icon, and works because I normally don't have permanent "desktop links". It is IMHO not as elegant as the Custom Application Launcher.